# How can I use select option value to display specific data from my API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, drop-down-menu

In my API data I have data for 12 semesters (from Fall16 to Fall23). With this code I am displaying the master schedule for all semesters, but I created a select option button where user can select what semester they want to see. How can I use the selected value to display specific data? for example, if user selects FALL22, the code should print the data where semester = fall22.

In the API Semesters are represented by numbers. with column = SemesterID (from 12 to 1) 12- fall22, and 1 - fall16.

```
import './Home.css';
import {React, useState } from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { DataGrid, GridToolbar } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import {getMasterSchedule} from "./SharedService";

const columns = [{field: "CRN", headerName: "CRN", width: 100},
                 {field: "CourseID", headerName: "Course ID", width: 90},
                 {field: "SectionNumber", headerName: "Section", width: 80},
                 {field: "CourseName", headerName: "Course Name", width: 300},
                 {field: "FirstName", headerName: "Professor", width: 85},
                 {field: "BuildingName", headerName: "Building", width: 150},
                 {field: "RoomNumber", headerName: "Room", width: 80},
                 {field: "SeatsAvailable", headerName: "Seats Available", width: 100},
                 {field: "StartTime", headerName: "Start Time", width: 100},
                 {field: "EndTime", headerName: "End Time", width: 100},
                 {field: "WeekDay", headerName: "Day", width: 100},
                 {field: "SemesterID", headerName: "SemesterID", width: 100}];

function MasterSchedule() {
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([])

  getMasterSchedule().then(x => {
    setTableData(x.data)
    }
  );

  const [semester, setSemester] = useState();
  return (
    <>
  
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <br></br>
  <h1>MASTER SCHEDULE - {semester}</h1>

  <div>
    <h3>Select Semester</h3>
      <select id="semester" value={semester} 
              onChange={(e) => setSemester(e.target.value)}>
              <option value="">--</option>
              <option value="FALL23">FALL23</option>
              <option value ="SPRING23">SPRING23</option> 
              <option value ="FALL22">FALL22</option>
              <option value ="SPRING22">SPRING22</option>
              <option value ="FALL21">FALL21</option>
              <option value ="SPRING21">SPRING21</option>
              <option value ="FALL20">FALL20</option>
              <option value ="SPRING20">SPRING20</option>
              <option value ="FALL19">FALL19</option>
              <option value ="SPRING19">SPRING19</option>
              <option value ="FALL18">FALL18</option>
              <option value ="SPRING18">SPRING18</option>
      </select>
      
    </div>


      <div style={{ height: 650, width: '100%' }}>
      <Box sx={{ height: 400, width: 1 }}>
        <DataGrid
          rows={tableData}
          columns={columns}
          pageSize={10}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
          getRowId={(row) => row.CRN}

          disableColumnFilter
          disableColumnSelector
          disableDensitySelector
          disableColumnMenu
          components={{ Toolbar: GridToolbar }}
          componentsProps={{
            toolbar: {
              showQuickFilter: true,
              quickFilterProps: { debounceMs: 500 },
            },
          }}
        />
        </Box>
      </div>
      

  
</>

  );
}

export default MasterSchedule;
```

Comment: Protip: Don't use line breaks for spacing. That's not their purpose and it makes a mess of your markup. Use margin, padding, flex alignment, etc.

Answer (score -1):

with dropdown it's always suggested to use key value pairs.
try implementing dropdown by taking the reference of the link. then your options to dropdown must look like
const options = [
{ label: "fall 16", value: 1 },
.
.
.
.
.
{ label: "fall 22", value: 12 }
];

with this you can be able to get the correct semesterId for the selected option
https://codesandbox.io/s/hqukt?file=/src/Components/DropdownEXP.js